# Partition by user defined dates sql

Tags: sql

I have a table which gives unit sales of different items by day. I want to sum the sales for a number of user-defined (effectively arbitrary, no way to specify directly from the data) periods.

I'm trying to do this by creating a field that specifies whether what period date is within, then I can group by this. However my code is giving me the error "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected".

MY CODE:

```
select
SUM(UNIT_SALES),
PERIOD =
    CASE 
             WHEN DAY_DATE >= TO_DATE('04/07/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND DAY_DATE <= TO_DATE('26/09/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'Start of Period of pre_activity'
             WHEN DAY_DATE >= TO_DATE('27/09/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND DAY_DATE <= TO_DATE('01/04/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'Start of Period of pre_activity'
             WHEN DAY_DATE >= TO_DATE('14/05/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND DAY_DATE <= TO_DATE('21/09/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'Start of Period of pre_activity'
             ELSE 'NO PERIOD ASSIGNED'
    END
FROM MY_SALES_DAILY
GROUP BY PERIOD
ORDER BY PERIOD
```

How can I achieve this sum for user-defined periods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. `PERIOD =` is incorrect. See the corrected SQL below.

```
select
SUM(UNIT_SALES),
    CASE 
             WHEN DAY_DATE >= TO_DATE('04/07/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND DAY_DATE <= TO_DATE('26/09/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'Start of Period of pre_activity'
             WHEN DAY_DATE >= TO_DATE('27/09/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND DAY_DATE <= TO_DATE('01/04/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'Start of Period of pre_activity'
             WHEN DAY_DATE >= TO_DATE('14/05/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND DAY_DATE <= TO_DATE('21/09/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'Start of Period of pre_activity'
             ELSE 'NO PERIOD ASSIGNED'
    END AS PERIOD
FROM DW_MASTER_SALES_DAILY
GROUP BY     CASE 
             WHEN DAY_DATE >= TO_DATE('04/07/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND DAY_DATE <= TO_DATE('26/09/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'Start of Period of pre_activity'
             WHEN DAY_DATE >= TO_DATE('27/09/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND DAY_DATE <= TO_DATE('01/04/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'Start of Period of pre_activity'
             WHEN DAY_DATE >= TO_DATE('14/05/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND DAY_DATE <= TO_DATE('21/09/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'Start of Period of pre_activity'
             ELSE 'NO PERIOD ASSIGNED'
             END
ORDER BY PERIOD
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. On using your code I'm getting the error "INVALID SQL STATEMENT". However I'm using TOAD which I've found likes slightly different syntax to what I've used previously. Can I ask what you're using for your code?

Comment: I'm using TSQL in this example. What RDBMS are you using? Oracle, mysql, ?

Comment: Hello, sorry that turned out not to be the issue. I needed to bring the case into the group by, now it works. I've edited the answer. Thanks for your help.